# How can i tell the StreamWriter when writing whats in the textBox1 to separate each string after a ,?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Grads_Scripts
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string cmd = "";
        string exepath = @"C:\OpenGrADS\Contents\Cygwin\Versions\2.0.2.oga.2\i686\opengrads.exe";
        private static StringBuilder cmdOutput = null;
        Process cmdProcess;
        StreamWriter cmdStreamWriter;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            cmd = "set xsize 650 500";
            ProcessCommands();
        }

        private void ProcessCommands()
        {
            cmdOutput = new StringBuilder("");
            cmdProcess = new Process();

            cmdProcess.StartInfo.FileName = exepath;
            cmdProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            cmdProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            cmdProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

            cmdProcess.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(SortOutputHandler);
            cmdProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            cmdProcess.Start();

            cmdStreamWriter = cmdProcess.StandardInput;
            cmdProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
        }



        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cmdStreamWriter.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox2.Text = cmdOutput.ToString();
            textBox2.AppendText(textBox1.Text);
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cmdStreamWriter.Close();
            cmdProcess.WaitForExit();
            cmdProcess.Close();
        }

        private static void SortOutputHandler(object sendingProcess,
            DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(outLine.Data))
            {
                cmdOutput.Append(Environment.NewLine + outLine.Data);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When i type in the textBox1 a command for example: set xsize 650 500 then click the button1 to execute the command it will do this command.

But now i want to be able to type more then one command for example in the textBox1 if i will type: set xsize 650 500,clear
And then click on button1 i want it to separate the two commands the first one is set xsize 650 500 and the second command is clear i will know it by the , that separate them

So what i want to do is here:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cmdStreamWriter.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);
        }
```

I click only once and it will make the first command set xsize 650 500 and then automatic right after will do the second command clear so i will not need to type every single command and click the button and then type another command and click the button but to enter batch of commands separate by , and it will execute each command automatic one by one.

By logical like a list or queue of commands and it will execute command one by one automatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use split and then loop through each string

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] cmdTextParts = textBox1.Text.Split(',');
        foreach (string item in cmdTextParts)
        {
            cmdStreamWriter.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
```